# PowerShell script to count characters

Tags: powershell

I found a command that works in the terminal that lists all the files of a given directory. I was wondering if it would be possible to use this in a script. I am supposed to have a script that lists all files with path length greater than 259 characters in a text file.

Here is the command:

```
dir /s /b /o:gn
```

Answer (score 1):

List all files in a given directory (e.g., *C:\MyFolder*):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\MyFolder -File
```

Filter for those where the full path is longer than 259 characters:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\MyFolder -File |
  Where-Object{$_.FullName.Length -gt 259}
```

Write the full paths to a text file, e.g. *C:\MyFile.txt*:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\MyFolder -File |
  Where-Object{$_.FullName.Length -gt 259} |
    Select-Object Fullname |
      Out-File C:\MyFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Where-Object{$_.FullName.Length -gt 259}
```

references the file's size. A small file size length will amount to a number something like 35328 - which is much greater than 259.

This will count the number of characters in the $_FullName path:

```
$characters = ($_.FullName)
$cFullName = $characters.length
```

Call on it with:

```
$CFullName
```